# Orientación con `pandas` y `dataFrame` en Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Soy nuevo con python y estoy haciendo una serie de ejercicios.

El caso es que tengo un `dataFrame` creado a partir de un diccionario:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'animal':
['gato', 'gato', 'serpiente', 'perro', 'perro', 'gato', 'serpiente', 'gato', 'perro', 'perro'],
'edad': [2.5, 3, 0.5, np.nan, 5, 2, 4.5, np.nan, 7, 3],
'visitas': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
'prioridad':
['si', 'si', 'no', 'si', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'si', 'no', 'no']
},index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
)
```

Por lo que quedaría algo así:

```
      animal    edad    visitas     prioridad
a       gato    2.5        1        si
b       gato    3.0        3        si
c   serpiente   0.5        2        no
d    perro      NaN        3        si
e   perro       5.0        2        no
f   gato        2.0        3        no
g   serpiente   4.5        1        no
h   gato        NaN        1        si
i   perro       7.0        2        no
j   perro       1.5        1        no
```

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

> Para cada número diferente de visitas de cada animal, calcule la edad promedio, es decir, devuelva una tabla, la fila es del tipo animal, la columna es el número de visitas y el valor de la tabla es la edad promedio del número. de visitantes en la columna de tipo de animal.

Y lo que entiendo es que tengo que hacer algo así:

```
           1    3     2
perro      x    x     x
gato       x    x     x
serpiente  x    x     x
```

Donde `x` es la edad media de los perros que tienen 1 visita, 2 visitas y 3, así con los demás animales. Pero no sé ni por dónde empezar.

¿Alguien puede orientarme aunque sea un poco?

Comment: Pero ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? ¿Cuál es el error que te impide hacerlo?

Comment: Aparte del comentario anterior, ¿Cómo se deberían considerar los `NaN`? Cómo dato inválido o como cero.

Comment: Si disculpa. Los NaN los elimino con dropNa para no interferir en la media. He creado la columna de los animales así. 
var = df.groupby(['animal','visitas'])['edad'].mean()
df_nuevo = pd.DataFrame(var)

Pero no me crea las columnas bien

Comment: Más bien creo que el ejercicio apunta a aprender sobre `pivot_table`, creo que con esa pista te puede ayudar, si al intentar no funciona por favor edita la pregunta y agrega lo que intentaste y lo revisamos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! he estado investigando y tengo esto:
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df.groupby(['animal','visitas']).size().to_frame()[:15]

df.pivot_table(df,index=['animal'],
               columns=['visitas'])
Con esto logro crear la tabla mas o menos como quiero, pero no se como rellenarla con la Edad Media de cada animal/visita

Comment: vale, ya lo he conseguido con esto
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
values=['edad'], 
index=['animal'], 
columns=['visitas'], 
aggfunc={'edad': np.mean}
)

df_pivot

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado. SImplemente borra la solución de la propia pregunta y respóndete a ti mismo con la solución. De tal forma otros podrán ver la solución fácilmente y, cuando des la respuesta por buena, se etiquetará como tal.

Comment: Considera también añadir una descripción detallada del por qué has aplicado esa solución y qué hace exactamente, para los que puedan estar en tu misma situación.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he podido solucionarlo

esta es la solución que he aplicado
Ya lo he solucionado.

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
values=['edad'], 
index=['animal'], 
columns=['visitas'], 
aggfunc={'edad': np.mean}
)

df_pivot
```

Primero he limpiado los datos de NaN, para no interferir en la media de la edad.
He usado el pivot_table. Son las agrupaciones de datos a las que se les suelen aplicar funciones matemáticas como sumatorios, promedios, etc.

Así que uso como valores las edades ya limpias, los animales como indices y las visitas como columnas. Se le agrega la función de mean() a la edad y se crea la tabla

Comment: Después de un par de días regresa a esta pregunta y acepta tu respuesta como correcta, de esa forma la pregunta no quedará abierta por siempre. Saludos!

Comment: Buen día, ya es posible que aceptes tu propia respuesta, por cierto, si quisieras resolverlo sin tener que importar `numpy` puedes hacer `aggfunc={'edad': 'mean'}`